# Free HTTP Tunnel client and server for Windows

Tags: http, tunnel

I'm looking for a client and server-application to tunnel communication through a company network. Its firewall is only open on port 80.

The server will be my PC at home.

Which application can you recommend. Freeware would be great but I'd also pay some money for a viable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure OpenVNC to use port 80, but it won't use the http protocol.

If you have to use http (e.g. to pass through a proxy or a firewall check), you can check out the GNU httptunnel tool (which should have a Windows version).

Alternatively, use the SSTP protocol. The client is shipped with Windows Vista and 7, but the server is unlikely to be free.

Comment: GNU httptunnel tool is pretty good. Windows binaries are available here http://neophob.com/2006/10/gnu-httptunnel-v33-windows-binaries/

Answer (score 1):

A good free tunnel server and client is available [here](http://www.zenz-solutions.de/personalhttptunnel/).

Answer (score 1):

A true HTTP Tunnel client/server combo is not trivial to set up. I have had success with the unimaginatively-named [HTTPTunnel](http://http-tunnel.sourceforge.net/), which is open source. There is a similarly named commercial product/service which I do not recommend.

The easiest solution would be to pay for a commercial HTTP Tunnel service like [PingFu](http://www.artofping.com/). It's only about $5 a month. I was testing it this week, and it works very well.